# TypeScript error "not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'" for React component with extended discriminated union

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### Problem:

I have an array of objects whose interfaces all extend a base interface.

I want to map these objects onto a React component which will route to specialised components for each of the supported child interfaces -- but first, I want to map over the array and extend each object with an `onClick` handler, whose signature is a generic which I want to specialise to suit whichever child interface it's being mapped onto.

I've come up with a solution that looks as though it should work, but I can't shake this TS error: `Type 'AWithClick<T>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes`. I see plenty of references in SO and elsewhere to TS errors related to that interface, but none quite seems to apply here.

I checked my solution against [this helpful article](https://blog.andrewbran.ch/expressive-react-component-apis-with-discriminated-unions), and I think the main difference in my implementation is that I'm trying to extend items from the union with specialised `onClick`s, rather than defining the specialised `onClick`s in the individual interfaces in the original union. The array of objects comes from a store, and I'm basically mapping its entities to component props, so I want to keep component props interfaces separate from the store interfaces.

#### Steps to repro:

`npx create-react-app repro --template typescript`

Replace App.tsx with the following:

```
import React from 'react';

enum AType { 'as', 'an' }

interface A {
  type: AType;
}

interface AS extends A {
  type: AType.as;
  value: string;
}

interface AN extends A {
  type: AType.an;
  value: number;
}

type AnyA = AS | AN;

type AWithClick<T extends AnyA> = T & { onClick: (value: T['value']) => void }

const ASComponent = (props: AWithClick<AS>) => <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>;
const ANComponent = (props: AWithClick<AN>) => <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>;

const TestComponent = <T extends AnyA>(props: AWithClick<T>) => {
  switch (props.type) {
    case AType.as: return <ASComponent {...props} />;
    case AType.an: return <ANComponent {...props} />;
  }
};

const withoutClicks = [
  { type: AType.as, value: 'AS!' } as AS,
  { type: AType.an, value: 1 } as AN,
];

const withClicks = withoutClicks.map(<T extends AnyA>(props: T) => ({
  ...props,
  onClick: (value: T['value']) => { console.log(value) },
}));

const TestComponentMain = () =>
  <div>
    {withClicks.map(props => <TestComponent {...props} key={props.type} />)}
  </div>
  
export default TestComponentMain;
```

Now `npm start` and you'll see the error `Type 'AWithClick<T>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that typescript can't quite follow the logic to know that you are refining the type adequately.

But `TestComponent` here does not need to be generic. You can simply declare your argument as the superset of what you support, and then refine the type with conditionals.

This works:

```
const TestComponent = (props: AWithClick<AnyA>) => {
  switch (props.type) {
    case AType.as: return <ASComponent {...props} />;
    case AType.an: return <ANComponent {...props} />;
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta&ssl=31&ssc=3&pln=26&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCqQDsBXPAQQBUBPMJOAbwJQGd8AGj618cAL5UqwWjCRRM6Lkx5U4cGByQAuOK20VKU6pVnzFy-QGU4SAB7zaAE3761lDVs56DnAHQCRhoAbigANvS6cPwwULIA5kYmMnIKSmgqAHJ2jnSu7tzqmtq+7AEotMFwYZHRDCAARgrJ0pTeKrRsqgC8NnAAPvpZRlQd+gDqwDAAFgDC4cBoANYAPCy5TgVMXUwAfHB9GwBkPHAQtAtLy3oAFLVReiwA2vgPSPgAugCUhwchEGAzkkbTQF1iNjmuEgtDo8D6tzAODA-F8U1mVxWqyY1j2vx6B1WjXoMBgF3Ol0WKx63Fu+IOSIgKP8F0xy0RyP4-ne3wke24jOZ7wkqwA9MTSRc9kYwbQIUwslDwBc4Yc4BymajJtN5lS1gq8X84ESSWTaBS2TS6UbBVzWXqNUKIlFefzbdznUgReLTVLRpRZRCWEhYkqYaqEba0Tq2djdoaCR4NPwAO7TNAzdXujq-IqeDRwNACFTlJCBLVEGD0KDm7HWMMquQ8fwt20SOCi6XFDRF-gl7SBWh6SvV2sKhuwpvcFv+Nsdrv5kwSf2B+Bp2YQElstx9Z7FXgdMoDgQid56fA4gCE4nbAhsQn3JR8+lLg9Pnr0AEZJHA7wqH5QnwruCa4xnqO5wOuMybjA27+CAKBgLc6ybPkbg7N0eyOlqLD0uqeYaDOtoARo9rXHcZ5wC8byel8eG8IGEDhGW4QQAk9yer8EgARI3zfMBcrwMGobQo2MAALIoLIarWgSxSrM4wAhHs3Y8FBcEIUhtpGusIawaJk7wNOracu2yxIGwNLZto7adry8miopynFDQ9iQLAcDOEgSj0OEQl6ROcKSbIpBAA)

---

In general, when troubleshooting error message with generics, it's always good ask the question "does this *really* need to be generic?"

Comment: Thanks, that solves it perfectly and saves me from madness.

I'm not sure I understand why `Type 'AWithClick<T>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'` was the error I was seeing - if you/anyone can make sense of that I'd love to understand - but regardless, this gets me out of trouble, so thanks!